# Microsoft Ergonomic 7000 keyboard + mouse lag

Tags: 12.04, xorg, hardware, radeon, wireless-keyboards

I recently bought a new Microsoft Ergonomic 7000 keyboard. I started to use it with my Ubuntu 12.04 and it lags all the time. I try to be more specific:

- Even on a minor CPU usage the mouse lags. By minor I mean firefox loading a webpage, or opening an application like conky, gnome-terminal etc.
- When higher CPU usage occurs the keyboard is lagging too, but by this I mean it misses my hits, so what I type won't appear later.

What I tried so far (and did not work)?

- Disable autosuspend (echo -1 to sys/bus/usb.../autosuspend) and at the same place set level to "on".
- I have tried several video drivers: Vesa, radeon, newest catalyst (and catalyst beta too)

When my keyboard and/or mouse lags I tried an other USB keyboard which works perfectly and the same for the mouse. I tried the keyboard and mouse on a different computer with Linux (Ubuntu, Arch, OpenSuse) too, the same problem appears but not on Windows.

I tried to replace the battery sets, and to change channel on the dongle. And also tried to use the dongle from other USB ports. On the same time I am able to use any other wireless mouse.

I changed the XkbModel to "microsoft7000" but it did not solve anything.

About the hardware:

- AMD A8 3870K -> Radeon HD6550D
- 8 GB of memory
- 4 GB of swap (which is almost never used)

Here are my PC's details:

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 045e:071d Microsoft Corp.   
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0461:4ea7 Primax Electronics, Ltd
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Complex  
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6550D]  
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)  
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)  
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)  
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)  
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)  
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SMBus Controller (rev 13)  
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson IDE Controller  
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson Azalia Controller (rev 01)  
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson LPC Bridge (rev 11)  
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson PCI Bridge (rev 40)  
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)  
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 43a0  
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 43a1  
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)  
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)  
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0   (rev 43)  
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1  
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2  
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3  
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4  
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6  
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5  
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7  
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

`dmesg | tail -n 150`: http://pastebin.com/sGUAAiUe
`cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`: http://pastebin.com/fny7ZkN4

Note: The Icon7 Twister Evolution is the replacement mouse to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backported more recent version of the video card driver `fglrx` driver solved my problem. I've found the [PPA X-updates](http://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) providing this.